# Cannot start gunicorn under Circus

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-14.04, gunicorn, circusd

When I tried to run the gunicorn directly, it worked:

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8081 ecerp.wsgi --chdir /var/www/django/ecerp_set/demo/ecerp/
```

But I kept trying with failed when using circus.

```
[circus]
check_delay = 5
endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5555
pubsub_endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5556
statsd = true

[watcher:ecerp]
cmd = gunicorn
args = -b 127.0.0.1:8081 ecerp.wsgi
working_dir = /var/www/django/ecerp_set/demo/ecerp
send_hup = true
```

And when I run `circusctl`, it shows that the app `ecerp` did not run:

```
root@vps3:~# circusctl
circusctl 0.11.1
ecerp: stopped
(circusctl)
```

Please help me point out where is wrong? I've spent half a day on it, thanks very much!

Comment: Quick checklist: 1) check for different env. variables (e.g. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, PYTHONPATH, PATH). 2) Check which user circus tries to use 3) Check for hang-up instances of gunicorn... sometimes circus is configured to kill the process with a signal that the process ignores, but it should be configurable.

Comment: @dsign Can you tell a more detail operations for me to follow?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using circus, then runit, somehow it just wan not figuring.
That is when I turned to using Systemd option

I tried using the systemd option and it worked, 
I have published the answer here..

https://askubuntu.com/questions/930589/running-upstart-script-on-17-04/1010398#1010398